# Some problems in insertion of code snippet inside Joomla articles

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, geshi

I am using Joomla 2.5 for my technical blog. In my articles I put some code snippet using the preinstalled Code Highlighter (GeSHi) plugin.

So, I insert a code snippet in the following way:

I open my editor in HTML mode and I put inside it the following code:

```
<pre xml:java="" lines="true">/**
 * The HelloWorldApp class implements an application that
 * simply prints "Hello World!" to standard output.
 */
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
</pre>
```

The snipped is well shown in my article, as you can see here (for example): 
http://scorejava.com/index.php/spring-spring-mvc/corso-spring-core-framework/53-18-autowiring-mediante-costruttore-in-spring

The problem is that if I try to do a copy and paste of a code there is inside a snippet (for example if I paste it in the notepad), this lost the indentation :-(

Why? What is wrong?

Tnx
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

No problem for me! Copy & Paste and content is correctly formed